# Как прокинуть параметр из мета-класса в дочерний класс?

Tags: python

Есть код

```
class ModelMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, table=False, **kwargs):
        def init(self, *args):
            for field, value in zip(namespace["__annotations__"], args):
                setattr(self, field, value)

        namespace["__init__"] = init
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)


class Model(metaclass=ModelMeta):
    @classmethod
    def get_tablename(cls):
        tablename = cls.__name__.lower()
        if hasattr(cls, '__tablename__'):
            tablename = getattr(cls, '__tablename__')
        return tablename


class User(Model, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    username: str
    password: str
    age: int
```

При создании новой модели можно указать параметр `table`, который мне нужен в классе `Model`, чтобы исходя из состояний этого параметра (True или False) писать разную логику.

Как получить доступ к параметру `table` мета-класса `ModelMeta` из класса `Model`.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `__new__` сохраните в атрибут класса:

```
class ModelMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, table=False, **kwargs):
        def init(self, *args):
            for field, value in zip(namespace["__annotations__"], args):
                setattr(self, field, value)

        namespace["__init__"] = init
        namespace["_table"] = table
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)


class Model(metaclass=ModelMeta):
    @classmethod
    def get_tablename(cls):
        tablename = cls.__name__.lower()
        if hasattr(cls, '__tablename__'):
            tablename = getattr(cls, '__tablename__')
        return tablename

    def get_table(self):
        return self._table
```